Dynamic import fails on build
I have a sveltekit app which I've been trying to optimise images for.
Here's some code that I use to optimise images, it uses vite dynamic import to dynamically load the image in question:
        const src = (
            await import(
                /* @vite-ignore */
                `/static${image.split('.')[0]}.${
                    image.split('.')[1]
                }?enhanced=true&w=2400;2000;1600;1200;800;400`
            )
        ).default as Image | null;

It works well in dev but as soon as I try to build in prod, I get:
Error in importImage: Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/static/img/test-author.webp' imported from /Users/jamie/source/repos/test-app/.svelte-kit/output/server/chunks/Image.js
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)
at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:324:11)
at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:943:10)
at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1129:11)
at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:835:30)
at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:424:18)
at ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:524:22)
at importModuleDynamically (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:110:35)
at importModuleDynamicallyCallback (node:internal/process/esm_loader:35:14) {
code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
